# Symfony2 run sql dataset script before each functional test

Tags: symfony, controller, functional-testing

I need to test my conrollers via functional tests.
How I can run plain sql script to revert database to default state before each execution of functional test?

Comment: The [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle) can get you there, just not with a single script.  Instead,  you can define a data fixture or set of fixtures that set a test database to a given state.  If your default state is empty, the bundle makes it very easy.  See documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your test functionnal tool but with Behat, I can init the static function "prepare". [Behat web site](http://docs.behat.org/guides/3.hooks.html)

```
/**
 * @BeforeSuite
 */
public static function prepare(SuiteEvent $event)
{
    $base = 'php ' . escapeshellarg(__DIR__ . '/../../app/console') . ' ';

    $commands = [
        $base . 'cache:clear',
        $base . 'doctrine:schema:drop --force',
        $base . 'doctrine:schema:create',
        $base . 'doctrine:fixture:load --append',
    ];
    foreach ($commands as $command) {
        echo $command . "\n";
        $process = new Process($command);
        $process->run();
    }
}
```

So, I drop database, create new and load all fixtures, now, all tests can be run.